# Regex not working in APEX, working on RegexPlanet

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a validation for a field where the user should enter an Oracle JDBC Thin connection URL, like:

- `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.2.1:1521/XE`
- `jdbc:oracle:thin:192.168.2.1:1521:X01A`
- `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.2.1:1521/COM.EXAMPLE`

I tried testing the regex with [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) and it says it's working (the regex I am using):

```
^jdbc:oracle:thin:[@//]*[.\w]+:\d+[:]*[/]*[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$
```

But when I try to validate the form using this regex it shows the error message, even when I am using the exact same URL's as the one's above. Other validations are working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JDBC Thin Driver Connection string can take one of these formats:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@[HOST][:PORT]:SID
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE
jdbc:oracle:thin:[USER/PASSWORD]@[HOST][:PORT]:SID
jdbc:oracle:thin:[USER/PASSWORD]@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE
```

Where `HOST` can be an IP Address or a name.

If you ignore the username/password then a regular expression to match is something like:

```
^jdbc:oracle:thin:@(//)?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\w+):\d+[:/][a-zA-Z0-9.]+$
```

*(although it's not perfect - but a perfect regular expression to match this would be huge)*

**Query**:

```
WITH connections ( conn ) AS (
  SELECT 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.2.1:1521/XE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.1:1521:X01A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.2.1:1521/COM.EXAMPLE' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM   connections
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( conn, '^jdbc:oracle:thin:@(//)?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\w+):\d+[:/][a-zA-Z0-9.]+$' );
```

**Results**:

```
CONN                                           
------------------------------------------------
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.2.1:1521/XE          
jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.1:1521:X01A          
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.2.1:1521/COM.EXAMPLE
```

Comment: Thank you very much, although an URL using a hostname is not working yet, this really helped me a lot and I should be able to alter it to accept hostnames too (I didn't include it in the question, sorry for that). Will post it later in a comment as it isn't the answer to this exact question.

Comment: I have now come up with: ^jdbc:oracle:thin:@(//)?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\w+|[a-zA-Z0-9.]+):\d+[:/][a-zA-Z0-9.]+$ as it isn't actually clear to me what \w means I didn't replace it. Thanks again, it's now fully functional for my intended usage.

Comment: From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDGHBHF): `\w` is the same as `[[:alnum:]_]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If you add an underscore (`_`) to your pattern then you can remove the `|\w+` bit.